# Styling a custom View deriving from Button in Xamarin Forms does not apply the text color

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-controls, styling, resourcedictionary

I am trying to create a custom button, with some additional behaviour that derives from the standard `Button` class. It is a very simple class that current is defined by simply the following:

```
public class SimpleCustomButton : Button
{
    public SimpleCustomButton()
    {
    }
}
```

To test styling this I created the following page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="UIKit.TestPage"
             xmlns:uikit="clr-namespace:UIKit"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
           <Button Text="GlobalStyling normalButton" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  />
           <uikit:SimpleCustomButton Text="GlobalStyling customButton" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start"  />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I applied the following styling to it, defining it globally in the app.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="UIKit.App"
             xmlns:uikit="clr-namespace:UIKit">
    <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="uikit:SimpleCustomButton">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**This results in the following:**

[image: The result running in the iOS simulator]

So the `Button` is rendered with a green background, red border and **red** text color.
The `uikit:SimpleCustomButton` is rendered with a green background, red border and **standard blue** text color.

So my main question is:

Why are only some of the style properties applied to the  `uikit:SimpleCustomButton` that derives from `Button`, but all of them to the normal `Button`.

Comment: What styles are being merged in with `<uikit:Style/>`?

Comment: Oops, this was an empty resource dictionary for another test. Removed it for clarity. Checked if I still had the same result just to be sure, and I still do.

Comment: One thing you could try is on your first Style with `TargetType="Button"`, also add `ApplyToDerivedTypes="True"`. This will allow you to only specify one style and not need the second one to your specific button type.

Comment: @TaylorD Thank you for the suggestion. This does not fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Try clean your solution delete bin and obj folder and rebuild I cannot reproduce.